# mysql exception while importing csv file to mysql database

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, sqlexception

i would like to import csv file in mysql database.

my query would be like the following.

query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+"' INTO TABLE testtable  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (text,price)";

But i got the following error while importing file.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

for full source code you can see  http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t53674.html.

Any Help is greatly appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can see http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t53674.html for more detail. i got same error while implementing the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [the user you are using does not have the privileges to load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file)
2. you might also need to specify [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
3. [make use user root allowed to access other than from localhost](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html)

Answer (score 0):

as error shows, you should double check if user-password-host-db combination is correct. this is what the error tells you.

Comment: Thanks jancha. my username,password and databasename is absolutely correct, still i got the same error.

Comment: If i tried other sql statment then it's working properly. but when i fired the following query, i get the same error. **query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+"' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (text,price)";**

Comment: so, if you can execute other query, could be also grants issue. also, make sure that the file you are trying to load is "readable" by the user that is executing your script.

Comment: Thanks for your help. my issue is solved now. The problem is that i don't have privileges to load data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are allowed to log into the database as root and you have the correct password in your connect string (caspian)

```
Connection conn = db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","caspian");
```

Comment: If i tried other sql statment then it's working properly. but when i fired the following query, i get the same error. **query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+"' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (text,price)";**

Comment: That is strange. Could you post all your code, the whole exception stack and also indicate on which line the exception is thrown? thx

Comment: Thanks for your help. my issue is solved now. The problem is that i don't have privileges to load data.